# Count number of empty input boxes in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you calculate the number of input boxes with no value in a table row using jquery?

example:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr class="data" id="row5">
<td><input type="text" value="20%" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="10%" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

I'm looking for answer = 2

Comment: i looking for something like $('#row5 > td input[type=text][value=]').length, but obviously my jquery is wrong

Comment: ok, sorry guys, looks like i got it wrong again :empty didn't work, but its looks like .find('input:text[value=""]') does, will do some more testing and then reselect the correct answer

Comment: please look at my demo in my answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even that the OP claimed the answer as correct and working, this comes from the [api doc](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/):

> Some other elements, on the other hand, are empty (i.e. have no children) by definition: input, img, br, and hr, for example.

So actually, it should be impossible to do it with the :empty selector.

```
$('input:empty').length
```

or to be more specific:

```
$('#table1').find('input:empty').length
```

even more specific:

```
$('#table1').find('input[type=text]:empty').length
```

Comment: i think it's clear that `with no value in a table row` above... 'row' :)

Comment: are you sure about that? :p I guess I have to correct my answer, it seems like the :empty returns 'empty' by definition for input elements

Comment: ahh yes.. I have no doubt with the `:empty` at all... it's just that the question title says in a table row... not in a table.... ahh never mind.. :)

Comment: Am I out of line here? :empty really does work for empty values in input boxes?

Comment: title : `Count number of empty input boxes in table row`. In A Table Row... that is just my point... the OP's example is just 1 row... but I see it has an id of row5.. by that I can say there are lot's of row (`tr`)... and the OP wanted it by row... as in the title of the question above... not in a table... maybe like `$('#table1 tr').each(function() { $(this).find('input:empty').length });`

Comment: yes, that is correct. i retested everything and :empty does not work as first thought. thank you for the explanation

Comment: I'm now using .find('input:text[value=""]').length and it seems to work.

Comment: how can i check i the imput its different of empty or null?, i cant to check that just for one column

Answer (score 2):

You can do like:

```
alert($('#table1 input:text[value == ""]').length);
```

Comment: i think it's clear that `with no value in a table row` above... 'row' :)

Comment: @Reigel: Ultimately input will go inside the table>tr>td.

Comment: @Reigel: Nope, it counts empty text boxes in the table.

Comment: ahhh yeah... It's just I think he wanted it by rows... `..table row..` from above...

Comment: Getting `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #table1 input:text[value == ""]`